XmlElement .HasChildElement
Given XML of
<Element>Text</Element>

and
<Element>
    <Child>Text</Child>
</Element>

Is there an easy way to differentiate the one that has a Child Element vs just Text, which is a Child Node?
$xmlElement.HasChildNodes will return True for both. I can play games with $xmlElement.ChildNodes.Where({($_.NodeType -eq 'Element')}) but that is anything but elegant. What I really want is $xmlElement.HasChildElements but that doesn't seem to be an option, and trying to extend [Xml.XmlElement] in PowerShell is pretty miserable. I feel like the only option is to loop through all the child nodes and look for .NodeType -eq 'Element' and a count of 0 on that collection. But it feels like something that would be really common to need to do and thus have an easy way to do.

Please, use [edit], to improve the question, ans specify how/where you assigned a value to $xmlElement . (Like in a good [mre])

Try using xpath; something like:
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//Element[descendant::*]");

foreach($node in $nodes) {
    echo $node.OuterXml
    }

The output should be only:
<Element><Child>Text2</Child></Element>


Interesting. So Linq and XPath can do it, but the .NET [Xml.XmlElement] class can't. Good to know. For now I will stick with the loop using the [Xml.XmlElement] because I am using that kind of approach in a lot of other situations, so I don't really want to introduce a new approach, nor do I really want to refactor the whole thing.

@Gordon - Your choice, of course, but for more complex XML and searches, xpath should be your first choice, IMHO.

The thing is, there are some other things I am doing that either XPath can't do or it's a real pain. A major one is that I am validating user created XML, so I need to iterate over all the attributes to make sure required attributes are there and invalid ones aren't. [XmlElement] makes that easy, XPath basically can't do it. It's great for working with XML that is a known quantity, and not good for validation.
